# Scraping table with subscript <sub> data

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently having fun with scrapy and Python 3.6. My goal is to scrape all data from table with such html code:

```
<table class="table table-a">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <h2 class="text-center no-margin">Geometry</h2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="Depth of section">h = 267 mm</td>
                        <td rowspan="8" class="text-center">
                            <a href="http://www.staticstools.eu/assets/image/profile-ipea.png" target="_blank">
                                <img src="http://www.staticstools.eu/assets/image/profile-ipea-thumb.png" alt="Section IPEA" class="img-responsive">
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="Width of section">b = 135 mm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="Flange thickness">t<sub>f</sub> = 8.7 mm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="Web thickness">t<sub>w</sub> = 5.5 mm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="Radius of root fillet">r<sub>1</sub> = 15 mm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="Distance of centre of gravity along y-axis">y<sub>s</sub> = 67.5 mm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="Depth of straight portion of web">d = 219.6 mm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="Area of section">A = 3915 mm<sup>2</sup></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="Painting surface per unit lenght">A<sub>L</sub> = 1.04 m<sup>2</sup>.m<sup>-1</sup></td>
                        <td title="Mass per unit lenght">G = 30.7 kg.m<sup>-1</sup></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
```

In some rows I'm facing with `<sup>` and `<sub>` index formatting which makes everything harder. What I mean is, by using:

```
response.css('table.table.table-a td::text').extract()
```

Output is:

```
['\n                            ',
 '\n                        ',
 'h = 267 mm',
 '\n                            ',
 '\n                        ',
 'b = 135 mm',
 't',
 ' = 8.7 mm',
 't',
 ' = 5.5 mm',
 'r',
 ' = 15 mm',
 'y',
 ' = 67.5 mm',
 'd = 219.6 mm',
 'A = 3915 mm',
 'A',
 ' = 1.04 m',
 '.m',
 'G = 30.7 kg.m']
```

So everything is messed a bit. I can also include nested tags using:

```
response.css('table.table.table-a td *::text').extract()
```

with output as such:

```
['\n                            ',
 'Geometry',
 '\n                        ',
 'h = 267 mm',
 '\n                            ',
 '\n                                ',
 '\n                            ',
 '\n                        ',
 'b = 135 mm',
 't',
 'f',
 ' = 8.7 mm',
 't',
 'w',
 ' = 5.5 mm',
 'r',
 '1',
 ' = 15 mm',
 'y',
 's',
 ' = 67.5 mm',
 'd = 219.6 mm',
 'A = 3915 mm',
 '2',
 'A',
 'L',
 ' = 1.04 m',
 '2',
 '.m',
 '-1',
 'G = 30.7 kg.m',
 '-1']
```

I can of course post-process that data for some tweeking, but I was wondering if it's possible to achieve it during scraping? I want my output data to be as follows:

```
 ['h = 267 mm',
     'b = 135 mm',
     'tf = 8.7 mm',
     'tw = 5.5 mm',
     'r1 = 15 mm', 
     'ys = 67.5 mm',
     'd = 219.6 mm',
     'A = 3915 mm2',
     'AL = 1.04 m2.m-1',
     'G = 30.7 kg.m-1']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can process the data as much as you'd like in the parse method of your spider class. Something like the following works here:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'www.example.com'
        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # perform data below

        data = response.xpath("//table").extract()

        data = pd.read_html(data[0])[0]

        # perform data processing above

        yield {'data':data}
```

Run the following to save the resultant df to json:

```
scrapy crawl myscraper -o table.json
```

If want to look closer at some code to insert into the parsing method take a look at the following:

```
df = pd.read_html(html)[0]

df

    0               1
0   Geometry        NaN
1   h = 267 mm      NaN
2   b = 135 mm      NaN
3   tf = 8.7 mm     NaN
4   tw = 5.5 mm     NaN
5   r1 = 15 mm      NaN
6   ys = 67.5 mm    NaN
7   d = 219.6 mm    NaN
8   A = 3915 mm2    NaN
9   AL = 1.04 m2.m-1    G = 30.7 kg.m-1

df = pd.DataFrame([i.split(r' ') for i in df[0].map(str)])
df.drop([1,3], axis=1, inplace=True)

df

    0   2
0   Geometry    None
1   h   267
2   b   135
3   tf  8.7
4   tw  5.5
5   r1  15
6   ys  67.5
7   d   219.6
8   A   3915
9   AL  1.04
```

Comment: Of course I can, but that's not the point. I was wondering if it is possible via .css or .xpath. So, do you think Pandas will get it done?

Comment: Your question reads: "but I was wondering if it's possible to achieve it during scraping?". My response to that was yes. You have to use xpath and css to isolate the raw html and you can then process that with pandas with the parsing method of your scraper class.

Comment: The sooner I am back to pandas the happier I am, that Is why i suggested using pandas as soon as it makes sense.

Comment: Ok, that satisfies me. Thanks!